# yii2 pagination do not work

Tags: php, pagination, yii2

I made pagination but all the posts ( i got 8 of them) are shown on every page. I want to show 4 of them on each page. Where is my mistake? I think the problem is in `count($posts)` because in the other posts i was looking at, they was using `$posts->count()` but this method do not work for me. Appreciate every advice!

controller action :

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new PostSearch();
    $postModel = new \app\models\Post();
    $userModel = new \app\models\BlogUser();

    $posts = $postModel::find()->orderBy(['post_id' => SORT_DESC])->all();

    $pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => count($posts), 'pageSize' => 4]);

    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'postModel' => $postModel,
        'userModel' => $userModel,
        'posts' => $posts,
        'pagination' => $pagination
    ]);
}
```

view index.php :

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'posts']) ?>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <?php

                    foreach ($posts as $post)
                    {
                        $id = $post->user_id;

                        $user = $userModel::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();

                        echo "<div class='col-md-6 blog-post'>
                                  <div class='col-md-3 post-prof-img'>"
                                        . Html::img('../images/' . $user->image, ['alt' => 'image', 'class' => 'tall img-circle']) .
                                  "<p class='text-center title-par'><strong><em> $user->username </em></strong></p>
                                   <p class='text-center'> $post->date_create</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='col-md-9 post-cont'><p>"
                                        . Html::a('Click for more!',['view', 'id' => $post->post_id]) .
                                        "</p><label class='text-center'> $post->title : </label>
                                        <div class='fade-post'>
                                            $post->content
                                        </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>";
                    }

                ?>

            </div>
            <?php Pjax::end() ?>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <?= Html::a('Create Post', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
            <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn search-button', 'style' => 'color: blue']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: posts page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use dataProvider->pagination->pageSize (and not create a new pagination and pass to render)

```
  $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
  $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=4;
```

and in view  you could use eg:  a listview widget as

```
/* index.php view file*/

 <?= 
   ListView::widget([
     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   ]); 
 ?>
```

or a gridview

```
<?= GridView::widget([
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
      'filterModel' => $searchModel,
      'columns' => [
          ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
          'your_column1',
          'your_column2',
           .....

          ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
          'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:84px; font-size:18px;']],
      ],
  ]); ?>
```

Comment: Ok! I made it like you said but what should i do in the view? I am sorry i am just still new in yii2 and programming at all. Will edit my view also!
What i did was `LinkPagination::widget([ WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE ])`  :-)

Comment: which type of view  .. you need .. a gridview ?? .. a listview .. ??? ..normally the pagination is easy managed  by widget  (gridview or list view widget)   .. answer  updated ..

Comment: I just want to split my layout in pages with 4 posts in each one but maybe i didn't understand the pagination enought :) Will add image with my view to see what i am trying to do. There i got 6 posts and i want them to be 4 on this page and the rest on the second page. Maybe it is little advanced for me :)

Comment: I think is a little bit advanced . build a multi column list view with pagination .. .I  suggest you of starting with a single set based on gridview or search for proper yii2 extension with this kind of widget

Comment: Thank you very much for you time and advices  :-)